# Jive API. Unknown error occured when trying to obtain oauth2 access token using authorization grant flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, postman, jive

You can see the video of the request I made to get the access token using Oauth2.0 Authorization Code grant flow. Although I am able to get code using the step 1, I could not get access token as described in the api documentation.
Find the jive api documentation at 
https://jive.com/developer/

Find the video of the request I made using Postman at 
https://youtu.be/b7B49n7sbpg

Comment: dude, that's a 17 minute video!

Comment: Please watch it at 2x or 3x speed. You can use the extension for chrome browser.   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playback-speed-co/hdannnflhlmdablckfkjpleikpphncik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the issue. In both requests I make for the token I am not including any scopes. Now this will work for implicit Grant Flow but it will not work with the Auth Code flow. So in the initial requests be sure to add at least one valid scope or both public scopes like this:

https://auth.jive.com/oauth2/v2/grant?response_type=code&client_id=c7959b3f-b7a6-451b-8c98-252fcf950271&redirect_uri=https://promodaddy.com&scope=users.v1.lines.read%20calls.v2.initiate